# How to check a property has changed or not wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a property in viewmodel Problem.This belongs to a model in which there are many properties like collections,string,images.I open a window using this view model.I am trying to show some message to user if the property Problem(its child properties) values have changed.I made a flag **_isChanged** to track changes but it remains false.

```
 public Problem Problem
    {
        get { return _problem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _problem)
            {
                _problem = value;
                _isChanged=true;
                OnPropertyChanged("Problem");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it set to false somewhere else? Did you debug?

Comment: Yes at in by default it is false.On get true when Problem will change

Comment: You have to describe your problem in more detail, there is not enough information to help you here.

Comment: do one thing : In your OnPropertyChanged(string prop) method, set this flag to true if (prop == "Problem").

Answer (score 0):

Below the list of situations I can think of:

- The property `Problem` is never *set*
- The new value equals the old value
- `Problem` has a custom `operator =`
- `_isChanged` is set to `false` elsewhere
- You *set* the value on one object instance and inspect `_isChanged` of a different object instance

These are all things that happen outside of the code you shared, or in other words, `Problem` is most likely not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the properties inside the class Problem change, does not mean that the property Problem itself will change.
Inside these properties you have to do something like this (let's say Text is a property inside your Problem class):

```
public string Text {

    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _text)
        {
            _text = value;
            Parent.IsChanged = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Where Parent is a reference to your Problem object.